# Linear programming: Which extreme point is chosen when a constraint is added?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

I have a linear objective function $V'x$ I'm trying to maximize on a *cell*, $x \in [0,1]^n$. So obviously, I have one of the extreme points as the optimum. Now suppose I add a constraint of the form $A_1x \geq 0$, such that the existing optimum is no longer feasible. My question is: Is it possible that the new optimum is one of the old extreme points (i.e. one of the extreme points of $[0,1]^n$ other than the old optimum) rather than one of the newly created ones (by adding $A_1x \geq 0$)? We can assume away rare cases like $A_1x =0$ passes through one of the extreme points of $[0,1]^n$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new optimum must lie on $A_1x = 0$, assuming the original optimal solution was unique.

To see this, let $x^*$ be the original optimal solution (with $A_1 x^* < 0$) and let $y$ be any extreme point of $[0,1]^n$ with $A_1 y > 0$. Then along the line segment from $y$ to $x^*$:

- The objective value must be increasing, since $x^*$ has a better objective value than $y$.
- The points are all in $[0,1]^n$, since $[0,1]^n$ is convex.

Since $A_1x^* < 0$ and $A_1y > 0$, there is a point $tx^* + (1-t)y$ at which $A_1(tx^* + (1-t)y) = 0$. That point is a better point than $y$, therefore $y$ cannot be the optimal solution.

Therefore no extreme points of the new region with $A_1x < 0$ can be optimal solutions, and the optimal solution must satisfy $A_1x = 0$: it must lie on the newly added constraint.

---

If the original optimal solution was not unique, then it's possible that we cut off *some* but not *all* optimal solutions, in which case some points with $A_1x > 0$ might still be optimal. Even in that case, by moving towards $x^*$ from such a solution, we can find another optimal solution on the hyperplane $A_1 x= 0$.

Comment: This is very very helpful! Just one question: So an extreme point $X$ of $[0,1]^n$ was NOT one of the optima w/o the additional constraint, but became one with it, is a scenario which is possible only if $A_1x=0$ passes through $X$ right?

Comment: Exactly. If $A_1x = 0$ did *not* pass through $X$, then we can improve $X$ by moving in the direction of the original optimal solution, so it can't be optimal. Conversely, if a corner of $[0,1]^n$ is optimal, it must lie on $A_1 x = 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. :)

Comment: Also, does the above hold if we replace $A_1x \geq 0$ with a set of constraints, i.e. $Ax \geq 0$ where $A$ is a matrix? Can we say also in that case that the new solution must lie on at least one of the constraints $A_i x \geq 0$, where $A' = [A_1 \cdots A_m]$?

Comment: Yes; the reasoning is exactly the same.

Comment: I have posted a highly related problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3881367/linear-programming-changes-in-solution-when-an-equality-constraint-is-added 
Since you were so helpful with this one, would you consider having a look? I have posted my own solution as well and it shouldn't take more than 5 minutes for someone well-conversant in linear algebra to tell if it's correct.
Sincere apologies if this request is somehow against the rules.